# Parsing HTTP 'Last-Modified' Date string in PHP

Tags: php, date, date-formatting, last-modified

I am using `FileAPI` to get the HTTP-header Last-Modified time of a file, which is returning the following string:

```
Fri Oct 25 2013 12:04:10 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

This is then posted to PHP and I need it converted to something sensible, preferably a timestamp. Before you suggest it, `strtotime()` returns `FALSE`.

Can't seem to find any answer to this anywhere.

Comment: `echo strtotime('Fri Oct 25 2013 12:04:10 GMT+0100');` => `1382699050`. `strtotime()` IS able to parse this date format...

Comment: The string including the (GMT Daylight Time) as above? That's the complete string.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp http://3v4l.org/CStMB

Comment: Thank you @hek2mgl - that explains the problem I'm seeing - php version here is 5.3.3. Please add this as an answer so I can accept - I think it's the most useful explanation to anyone else encountering this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately since 5.3.0 there is [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php). Although it cannot parse the trailing information it is at least able to ignore it using the `+` specifier. You don't need that information in order to create a timestamp as you already have the, machine parsable, `GMT+0100`.

Example:

```
$str = "Fri Oct 25 2013 12:04:10 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
$fmt = 'D M d Y H:i:s O+';

$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($fmt, $str);
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Output:

```
1382699050
```

Comment: Thanks, although the regex wouldn't match until I removed the initial `.*`

Comment: Once you have $str from the preg_replace call, can't you just use ``strtotime($str)`` to get the timestamp?  I'm doing that, and then ``date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)`` to format the date for a mysql query, without problem (so far :) ).  Also, can this question be reworded to replace 'Formatting' to 'Parsing'?  Formatting sounds like converting data to a string, but you are actually trying to parse a string header to a value.

Comment: @Neek The `preg_replace()` isn't necessary. Check my update. I should have read the documentation more carefully when I've answered this. ;) You are right with the title of the question. I've changed this.

Comment: "`strtotime()` is able to parse the string only until PHP version 5.2.17" - this is untrue. I am using PHP 5.6.20 and I am able to use it fine: `strtotime("Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT");`.

Comment: I see. It's an old answer, I don't know where I had this from

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the problem is the string inside the parentheses, you could substring it to the first one and use `strtotime` as @Marcell suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but the accepted answer is based on the OP's question and not on the *real* format used by `Last-Modified` header. There is a missing comma (`,`) after the day of the week and the data order is not right.

The official [format for Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) header is:

```
Last-Modified: <day-name>, <day> <month> <year> <hour>:<minute>:<second> GMT
```

Therefore, the date format you get from the header should be different and the format to use already exists in the [DateTime interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) as `DateTimeInterface::RFC7231`:

```
$str = "Fri,25 Oct 2013 12:04:10 GMT";
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($fmt, $str);

echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

I know this is different from what the OP asked but the HTTP protocol has a different format than what was written by the OP.

This answer should be seen as complementary.